# About MapBox SDK

Tags: mapbox

i need to write a indoor navigation project for ios, i need to use a
custom map for a mall building, so i searched the web,  and found
`MapBox` was a good choice for my purpose.

I'm new to `MapBox`, so i have some questions regarding the SDK.

1. Do i must have a `free account` in order to use the SDK?
2. Do i have to use a `Map ID` in order to use the `RMMapboxSource`?
3. Does the SDK has any limitations to use, for example, maximum tiles, maximum layers?
4. I found that the SDK is using `CLLocationCoordinate2D` coordinates for the
   map, because i use the custom map(expressed in plain (x,y) coordinate) for
   indoor purpose, how to convert the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` coordinates to
   the plain (x,y) coordinate?

Could anyone out there helping me？

sorry for my bad english if i'm not clearly expressed myself?

and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to be a Mapbox customer (free or paid) to use the SDK. It's open source (BSD license).

To use the `RMMapboxSource`, yes, it's meant for `mapID`/hosted Mapbox maps. Check out `RMGenericMapSource` for a model for self-hosted or other tiles.

The SDK doesn't have any limitations other than what's performant in your use case.

For indoor coordinates, you should either convert to real `CLLocationCoordinate2D` at high precision or consider building your own solution using the SDK as a model, with `UIScrollView` and `CATiledLayer` as it does in order to not necessarily have a real geographic basis for your coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, And if i want to use the `RMMapboxSource`, Do i have to send my custom indoor map to `MapBox`?